# php Compare multiple strings against 1 value

Tags: php, operators

I have a fairly simple line of comparison code, it works, but I was wondering if there is a quicker / more efficient way of writing it.

```
if($RES > 0 AND $MarkerL1 != 'RES' AND $MarkerL2 != 'RES' AND $MarkerL3 != 'RES' AND $MarkerL4 != 'RES' AND $MarkerL5 != 'RES' AND $MarkerL6 != 'RES' AND $MarkerL7 != 'RES' AND $MarkerL8 != 'RES'){$PosNumL9 = 8; $NextPosL9 = $RES; $MarkerL9 = 'RES';}
```

Thanks

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: You can use `foreach` or `switch` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Can't the `$MarkerL$` variables be an array ?

Comment: Put the markers in an array and use `in_array` - if they're related data then having them in the same data structure makes sense anyway.

Comment: If you have several variables all called x1, x2, x3 etc., then you probably want an *array* of `$markers` instead, and you could use array operations across the array instead of individual repetitive variable comparisons.

Comment: Wouldn't this question be better suited over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

you try this code:

```
$RES > 0  AND !in_array('RES',[$MarkerL1, $MarkerL2, $MarkerL3, $MarkerL4, $MarkerL5, $MarkerL6, $MarkerL7, $MarkerL8])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do like that :

```
    $markers = [$MarkerL1,$MarkerL2,$MarkerL3,$MarkerL4,$MarkerL5,$MarkerL6,$MarkerL7,$MarkerL8,$MarkerL9];

if($RES > 0 AND !in_array('RES',$markers))
{
$PosNumL9 = 8; $NextPosL9 = $RES; $MarkerL9 = 'RES';
}
```

Hope that be good for you ..

Answer (score 0):

As some answers already underlined you can use :

```
!in_array('RES',[$MarkerL1, $MarkerL2, $MarkerL3, $MarkerL4, $MarkerL5, $MarkerL6, $MarkerL7, $MarkerL8]
```

as a shortcut for

```
$MarkerL1 != 'RES' AND $MarkerL2 != 'RES' AND $MarkerL3 != 'RES' AND $MarkerL4 != 'RES' AND $MarkerL5 != 'RES' AND $MarkerL6 != 'RES' AND $MarkerL7 != 'RES' AND $MarkerL8 != 'RES'
```

It works fine ...

You could also change your full code to:

```
for($i=1,$false=true;$i<9;$i++){
    if(${"MarkerL$i"}==='RES'){
        $false=false;
        break;
    }
}
($RES>0 && $false)? $PosNumL9 = 8 && $NextPosL9 = $RES && $MarkerL9 = 'RES':null;
```

It works really fine too

Comment: Thank you for all your help, sorry I didn't reply sooner been poorly. thanks I will try some of those suggestions now.